# Why can't I create a border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Here is my code which should work but does not.

```
self.square =[[UIView alloc]init];
self.square.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
//_square.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0  alpha:1];
[_square.layer setBorderColor: (__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0  alpha:1]];
_square.alpha=1.0;
[_square.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[previewView addSubview:_square];
```

The thing is, if I give the view a background color then the view is visible but if I dont, the view is not. What I am trying to do is get a square outline. So I figured if I get a view with no background color and a border, it would work.

Comment: if you downvote a question, have the decency to specify why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default UIView is transparent. You can achieve what you want, by setting different color for your view's background and border. Then adjust it as you wish.

You can do like this:

```
 _square.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[_square.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

don't typecast the UIColor to CGColor
try below code

```
[_square.layer setBorderColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0  alpha:1].CGColor];
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the typecast because I was getting an error. Did'nt know `.CGColor` was a thing

Comment: @nupac All you needed to do was look at the docs for `UIColor` to see the `CGColor` property.

Comment: Calm down man, the docs are huge and sometimes you miss some properties. I asked and you replied, end it there